# Key and Keyref constraints : how to choose "xs:selector"?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I have an XML document like this :

```
<a>
    <b name="OneB">
       <c name="OneC"/>
    </b>
    <b name="TwoB">
       <c name="TwoC"/>
    </b>

    <d Bname="OneB" Cname="OneC"/> <!-- Correct -->
    <d Bname="TwoB" Cname="TwoC"/> <!-- Correct -->
    <d Bname="OneB" Cname="TwoC"/> <!-- Wrong -->
    <d Bname="TwoB" Cname="OneC"/> <!-- Wrong -->
</a>
```

I want to write xs:key and xs:keyref in my XSD file that can only permit the right value of Cname attribute in "d" elements in this way : Cname value is a valid value only if it is a child of the Bname value element (like in the example).
How can I do this? I can't understand how because the xs:selector xpath expression doesn't allow to specify the attribute value ("@"). Is it possible to write xs:key and xs:keyref or maybe there is another solution I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with key and keyref because the XPath expressions don't allow predicates, and therefore can't depend on the actual values of attributes.

You'll need to use XSD 1.1 assertions (or a different technology, like Schematron). With XSD 1.1, you would define an assertion on the `<a>` element like this:

```
<xs:assert test="every $d in d satisfies 
                 some $b in b satisfies $d/@Cname = $b/c/@name
                              and $d/@Bname = $b/@name"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me.